# UITextField - apply custom padding on right and left side

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am trying to add padding on both sides of the custom textfield using following code

```
func rect(forBounds bounds:CGRect) -> CGRect {
     return bounds.insetBy(dx: 12, dy: 0)
}

override open func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
      var rect = super.textRect(forBounds: bounds)
      rect = self.rect(forBounds: rect)
      return rect
}

open override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
      var rect = super.editingRect(forBounds: bounds)
      rect = self.rect(forBounds: rect)
      return rect
}
```

[image: output looks like this]

Problem here is on the left hand side the padding appears perfectly, but on the right hand side the padding is not so consistent. I am not able to figure out what is causing the extra padding on the right side of the text.

Comment: Left View and Right view!

Comment: I need left and right view for different purpose

Comment: Btw your methods are in swift, why are you using objective c tag then?. I have added the swift tag. Please remove the objective C tag if not needed

Comment: problem exists in either of them, even code in swift or objective c

Comment: The text is probably left aligned causing the text not to extend all the way to the left -> "the padding will be bigger on the right side"

Comment: No. thats not the problem

Comment: Why not embed your textfield in a UIView ?